# count number of names in list in python

Tags: python

i have one list wich has names in it:

```
names = ['test','hallo','test']
uniquenames = ['test','hallo']
```

with set i get the uniquenames so the unique names are in a different list

but now i want to count how many names there are of each so test:2 hallo:1

i have this:

```
for i in range(len(uniquenames)):
    countname = name.count[i]
```

but it gives me this error:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
names = ['test','hallo','test']
countnames = {}
for name in names:
    countnames[name] = countnames.get(name, 0) + 1

print(countnames) # => {'test': 2, 'hallo': 1}
```

If you want to make it case-insensitive, use this:

```
names = ['test','hallo','test', 'HaLLo', 'tESt']
countnames = {}
for name in names:
    name = name.lower() # => to make 'test' and 'Test' and 'TeST'...etc the same
    countnames[name] = countnames.get(name, 0) + 1

print(countnames) # => {'test': 3, 'hallo': 2}
```

In case you want the keys to be the counts, use an array to store the names in:

```
names = ['test','hallo','test','name', 'HaLLo', 'tESt','name', 'Hi', 'hi', 'Name', 'once']
temp = {}
for name in names:
    name = name.lower()
    temp[name] = temp.get(name, 0) + 1

countnames = {}
for name, count in temp.items():
    countnames.setdefault(count, []).append(name)
print(countnames) # => {3: ['test', 'name'], 2: ['hallo', 'hi'], 1: ['once']}
```

Comment: Thanks one question
how can i rotate this?
so 3 becomes the key for example and the name becomes the index in the dictionary?

Comment: @klaashansen You can't do that, since keys must be different, and so if two names have the same count, only the last one will be registered, however, there is a workaround with arrays, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks marked as answer

Comment: @klaashansen Glad to help :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(names)
Counter({'test': 2, 'hallo': 1})
```

Also, for your example to work you should change `names.count[i]` for `names.count(i)` as `count` is a function.